# Cisco 2851, nodes on local network can access Internet but router can't

Tags: cisco, routing, nat

I am using a 2851, on GE0/1 I have a BT OpenReach VDSL modem and GE0/0 goes to a switch and the rest of my network. The desired configuration is pretty straight forward and mostly works, I want the router to handle the PPPoE for the modem, operate a typical NAT config (with some port forwarding) and DNS / DHCP. Simple right?

The problem I am experiencing is that while clients on my network can reach the Internet with no issues, when attempting to reach the Internet **from the router itself** it doesn't seem to be putting the packets in quite the right direction somewhere along the line...

Facts (NB, the router's IP is 192.168.1.254):

- The router is issuing DHCP leases with no issue
- From a PC on my network, I can ping '192.168.1.254'
- From a PC on my network, I can ping '8.8.8.8'.
- From a PC on my network, if I set my DNS server to '8.8.8.8', I can resolve 'google.com'.
- From a PC on my network, if I set my DNS server to '192.168.1.254', I can **not** resolve 'google.com'.
- From the router, I can ping clients on my local network
- From the router, I can **not** ping '8.8.8.8' using the command: **ping 8.8.8.8**
- From the router, I **can** ping '8.8.8.8' using the command: **ping 8.8.8.8 source 192.168.1.254**
- From the router, if I remove the NAT configuration, I can ping '8.8.8.8', I can also resolve 'google.com'

So, it would seem that while the router is perfectly capable of reaching out to the Internet and works fine for clients on my local network, something is not quite right with my configuration and it is preventing the router from reaching the Internet 'in its default state' (for lack of a better term).

One of the interesting things to me is that this (practically identical) configuration was working fine on an old 2611XM I have, albeit running a different version & feature set of IOS.

Here is the configuration:

```
!
version 15.1
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname 2800-router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication enable default none
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
!
dot11 syslog
no ip source-route
!
!
ip cef
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.49
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.200 192.168.1.254
!
ip dhcp pool default
   network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.1.254 
   dns-server 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 
!
!
!
ip domain name local
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 8.8.4.4
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
voice-card 0
!
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2851 sn ...
username ... privilege 15 secret 5 ...
!
redundancy
!
!
ip ssh version 2
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
 no ip unreachables
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface Dialer0
 ip address negotiated
 ip access-group 100 in
 no ip unreachables
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1
 ppp chap hostname ...
 ppp chap password 7 ...
 no cdp enable
!
no ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip dns server
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.1 6636 interface Dialer0 6636
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.1 6636 interface Dialer0 6636
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.2 28015 interface Dialer0 28015
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.1 30033 interface Dialer0 30033
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.1 10011 interface Dialer0 10011
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.1 9987 interface Dialer0 9987
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.1 80 interface Dialer0 80
ip nat inside source list 101 interface Dialer0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer0
!
logging esm config
access-list 100 permit ip any any
access-list 101 permit ip any any
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
mgcp profile default
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 transport input ssh
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Here is the output of 'sh ip ro':

```
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is 0.0.0.0 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 is directly connected, Dialer0
      192.168.1.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L        192.168.1.254/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
      195.166.xxx.xxx/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C        195.166.xxx.xxx is directly connected, Dialer0
      212.159.xxx.xxx/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C        212.159.xxx.xxx is directly connected, Dialer0
```

Output of 'sh ver':

```
Cisco IOS Software, 2800 Software (C2800NM-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.1(3)T4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Thu 24-May-12 01:38 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.4(13r)T, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

2800-router uptime is 3 hours, 44 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System image file is "flash:c2800nm-advipservicesk9-mz.151-3.T4.bin"
Last reload type: Normal Reload


This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

Cisco 2851 (revision 53.51) with 774144K/12288K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID xxx
2 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity enabled.
239K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
126000K bytes of ATA CompactFlash (Read/Write)


License Info:

License UDI:

-------------------------------------------------
Device#   PID                   SN
-------------------------------------------------
*0        CISCO2851             xxx



Configuration register is 0x2102
```

Comment: What is the IOS version this router is running ?

Comment: Hi drookie - i've added the output of 'sh ver' to the bottom of the post - bootstrap is 12.4(13r)T, image is c2800nm-advipservicesk9-mz.151-3.T4.bin

Comment: Your configuration looks valid. Furthermore, as you are saying, it has been proven working. Did you try to run this device with 12.4T IOS, last from the available ? That's what I'd do.

Comment: I had 12.4-12 and put it on there - seems to be working as expected... I wonder what's going on with the 15.1 version....

Comment: 15.х is too immature for legacy models.